# Android Git Tag in Jenkins

Tags: android, git, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build my Android project in that am using Multiple SCM, since I have both SVN and Git repo. Can anyone help me on the shell command or on Jenkins Git publish to tag my Git repo?. Because I would like to manage tagging my project  through Jenkins for my Git repo. (Note: For SVN I use the shell command for tagging and its working ).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following plug-in for Tagging the GIT repo.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin
Or use the hundson git publisher plug-in to tag
http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2013/03/hudson-jenkins-create-git-tags-branches-automatically/